# How to properly display date from csv in matplotlib plot?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib, plot

I have a csv with the following columns: recorded, humidity and temperature. I want to display the recorded values(date and time) on the x axis and the humidity on the y axis. How can I properly display the dates(it is quite a big csv), as my current plot has black instead of proper date numbers...  My date format is like this: 2019-09-12T07:26:55, having the date and also the time displayed in the csv.

I have displayed the plot using this code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('home_data.csv')
plt.plot(data.recorded, data.humidity)
plt.xlabel('date')
plt.ylabel('humidity')
plt.title('Visualizing date and humidity')
plt.show()
```

This is a print screen of the plot:
https://snipboard.io/d4hfS7.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the plot is displaying every date in your dataset. They are so many that they seem just like a black blob. You can downsample the xticks in order to increase the readability. Do something like this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(data.recorded, data.humidity)
# some axes labelling
# Reduce now the number of the ticks printed in the figure
ax.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks()[::4])
ax.get_xticklabels(ax.get_xticks(), rotation=45)
```

In line `ax.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks()[::4])` you are setting the ticks of the x-axis
picking 1 date every 4 using the property of the `list`. It will reduce the number of dates printed. You can increase the number as much as you want.
To increase the readibility, you can rotate the tick labels as I suggested in the line 
`ax.get_xticklabels(ax.get_xticks(), rotation=45)`.

Hope this helps.